# How to get response out the function to return through functions in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest

```
function api(method, body){
  console.log(body)
  unirest.post(BASE_URL + method)
  .send(body)
  .end(function (response) { 
        return response.body
  });
}
```

this api function is not returning what i mentioned

what could i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `return` in a callback, which is asynchronous.

*This* will work, but you will have to use `await` or `.then`

```
function api(method,body){
  let ret = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(body)
    unirest.post(BASE_URL + method)
    .send(body)
    .end(function (response) { 
      resolve(response.body)
    });
  return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason: `post` is an async call and by the time it receives the data from the request, the function is already executed and doesn't return anything. You can use promises to do get the result, you can  implement like this:

```
function api(method,body){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     console.log(body)
  unirest.post(BASE_URL + method)
  .send(body)
  .end(function (response) { 
        resolve(response.body);
  });
   //if there is any error you can call reject
   // reject('You error message');

 })
}

//to get the value you can use then/catch or async/await
api().then((data) => {console.log(`Data is ${data}`)})
.catch(console.log);
```

For more details about promises, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).